# How to add admob within a relativelayout

Tags: android, admob, android-relativelayout

I have developed an android application. My app will be used in landscape mode. Now I wanna place an ad at the left side vertically. Is it possible? if not then please how to place it horizontally at the top?

My layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/s1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/a_1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/s2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/a_2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/s3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/a_3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/s4" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/a_4" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp" />

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center" android:background="#00000000">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/l" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" android:background="@drawable/letterbackground"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:textSize="60sp"
        android:shadowColor="#AA42d68b" android:shadowRadius="1.5"
        android:shadowDx="5" android:shadowDy="5" android:text="A" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:id="@+id/menu_widget" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the admob AdView in your code (in your activity or fragment).  The ad will show up when you receive an actual ad (horizontally at the top).

Here is a sample that should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your.app.package"
        android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

    <Put the rest of the layout here>
    </Put the rest of the layout here>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

As of Admob version 6.4.1, you don't even have to instantiate the activity, you can add the ad as a view directly:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER"
                       ads:adUnitId="a151b78112c1df4"
                       ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,TEST_DEVICE_ID_GOES_HERE"
                       ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```